# Which passages or characters seen in Mistborn hint at the Cosmere?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, wax-wayne-novels

I'm looking for either characters, concept passages that are meant, *by Sanderson*, to refer to the greater Cosmere of his collective works.

However, I'm only interested in references in the 6 existing *Mistborn* novels, The Orignal Trilogy and the Wax & Wayne books. Support from the novella, *Mistborn: Secret History*, would be great.

Comment: so not secret history?

Comment: @Himarm I don't know what that is...

Comment: after bands of mourning he released a novella called mistborn: secret history (released jan 30-2016) its set during/after the original trilogy.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Mistborn-Secret-History-Brandon-Sanderson-ebook/dp/B01B0NS93U , your welcome go read it

Comment: @Himarm Looks like it's good. Updated.

Comment: The text at the beginning of each chapter of the original trilogy make the most references, outside of the Secret History.  There's even a passage there referring to Adonalsium.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, anything Cosmere will be an outside (not related to the existing creatures plus Harmony), and unexplained, influence.  To wit (pun intended):

- **Hoid.**  The cheeky bastard.  He appears in all six main *Mistborn* novels published to date, although in two he is identified only by word of the author (He's with the Terris in *Well* before they turn back to the city, and he's the beggar-type seen talking to the wedding couple at the reception Wax attends in *Alloy*), and in a third he is identified retroactively by seeing a scene from a new perspective in *Secret Histories*.  Hoid shows up in *Secret Histories* as well, named as the Drifter, but clearly described for anyone paying attention and doing things of import for once.  For the record, these appearances are at least centuries apart, considering the timeline, and points at a strange ability to know how to keep an eye on any particular main characters.
- > **Trell.** He is specifically identified as an outside influence on the world in *Bands of Mourning*, although he was likely on Scadrial at some point.  This in general points to the wider universe.
- The woman who dances with Wax briefly in New Seran, and seems to be researching his abilities.  She is researching most powers, and is hinted to be writing the appendixes that detail magic at the end of each novel.
- The journal excerpts that headline chapters in the original trilogy contain some small scraps, especially the ones from the Hero of Ages looking back at the events of the trilogy.  These specifically call out the mortal origins of Shardholders and name checks Adonalsium (as Kai points out in comment).
- Speaking of mortal origins, the fact that the both of the Shardholders in Mistborn, Preservation and Ruin, leave behind human bodies is a pretty big tipoff that once upon a time, there was yet another story we haven't heard yet.

Then we come to *Secret Histories*, which when you are digging for Cosmere clues in *Mistborn*, is kind of like uncovering an ancient tablet written in English saying you need to dig faster and about twenty feet to your left.

> *Secret Histories* explicitly shows more of the nature of the Cognitive Realm (which connects to all worlds and is part of the plot in *The Stormlight Archive*) from the perspective on someone who's supposed to be dead.  It shows several different groups travelling from different Cosmere worlds through the Cognitive Realm, hints at some of their motives, and more about Shards.

Comment: More than I expected!

Comment: I've been told that there's apparently some bits or characters that can be identified in the partial broadsheets put in the Wax and Wayne novels, too, but I'm not versed enough in Sanderson's mad plan, or psychic enough, to identify which.